# Search on field with json data

Tags: json, postgresql, search

i have a json array, f.e. `[169,172]` and i need a query to find if this array contains a number, f.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM smthg WHERE 169 IN '[169,172]'::json;
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select '[169,172]'::jsonb @> '169';
```

this is for postgres 9.4b2 using the jsonb type. For lower version numbers you may have to resort to a text search or something like this:

```
select true where '169' in (select json_array_elements_text('[169,172]'::json));
```